# Jquery next doesnt iterate correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on my own Slideshow and I'm already struggling in the beginning. At the moment I have two functions in my object:

```
init: function() {
    var self = this;
    if (this.element.find(".slide_item").size() == 1) {
        this.options.on = false;
    } else {
        setInterval(function() { self.next(); }, 5000);
    }
},

next: function() {
    var items = this.element.find(".slide_item");
    var current = this.element.find(".slide_item:visible");
    var next = current.next();

    current.slideUp("slow");
    if (next.is(":last-child")) {
        items.first().slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        next.slideDown("slow");
    }
}
```

I have three items in my slideshow-container (*.slideshow*) but my code actually only switches between the first and the second item. The third, the last item always gets passed by. I dont know why, when I check all the output with *console.log()*, everything seems to be fine. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Need your markup to see what's going on.  Can you jsfiddle it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (next.is(":last-child")) {
    items.first().slideDown("slow");
```

What this says is if the next item is the last item, slidedown the first, effectively skipping the last item.

What you instead want to do is if the next item doesn't exist, slide down the first item.

```
if (next.length == 0) {
    items.first().slideDown("slow");
```

I prefer to instead just update the `next` var with the first.

```
var next = current.next();
if (next.length == 0) {
    next = items.first();
}

current.slideUp("slow");
next.slideDown("slow");
```